# How can I get only unread emails using imapflow?

Tags: node.js, imap, imapflow

Good morning, I am using this library at work and I have a problem.

When I connect to the imapflow mail server it returns all the mails but I can't differentiate which ones are read and which ones are not read.

I have been reading the documentation (https://imapflow.com/) but I can't find anything that helped me. I have also tried using filters but nothing works.

Could you please help me?

I leave the code snippet where I am trying to get the unread emails.

Thank you very much for your help.

```
    const main = async (client) => {

let envelope = [];

await client.connect();

// At this point I have set the variable unseen to true but it doesn't work :(
let lock = await client.getMailboxLock('INBOX', {unseen: true});

try {
    let message = await client.fetchOne('*', { source: true });
    //console.log(message.source.toString());

    for await (let message of client.fetch('1:*', { envelope: true })) {
        
        envelope.push(message.envelope)
    }
} finally {
    lock.release();
}

await client.logout();

let reverse_envelope = envelope.reverse();

return reverse_envelope
};
```

Comment: I don't know this library, but the meta data about messages is contained the in the 'FLAGS' fetch item.  \Seen tells you whether it's been read, \Flagged if the user has marked it important, et.

Answer (score 4):

With `imapflow`, the solution is quite simple:

You can use [`client.fetch()`](https://imapflow.com/module-imapflow-ImapFlow.html#fetch) method with a [`SearchObject`](https://imapflow.com/global.html#SearchObject) as first parameter. As second parameter, you can use [`FetchQueryObject`](https://imapflow.com/global.html#FetchQueryObject):

```
await client.fetch({ seen: false }, { envelope: true });
```

What you pass in as `FetchQueryObject` may vary, and you can pass different options to the `SearchObject`, too, more info can be found in the [docs](https://imapflow.com/global.html) :)

I am using this code:

```
let emails; 
for await (let msg of client.fetch(
      { seen: false },
      {
        flage: true,
        envelope: true,
        source: false,
        bodyParts: true,
        bodyStructure: true,
        uid: true, 
      }
    )) {
      emails.push(msg);
    }
// use emails here
```

But: Make sure that you only use this code in when you currently locked the Mailbox, otherwise you will always get an empty array as result.